# Using a Keras DataGenerator with a Triplet network

Tags: python, keras, plaidml

I am currently trying to implement a network that is training on image triplets. For this, I adapted a par generator I found on the Internet:

```
def triplet_generator(triples, image_cache, datagens, batch_size=32):
    while True:
        # shuffle once per batch
        indices = np.random.permutation(np.arange(len(triples)))
        num_batches = len(triples) // batch_size
        for bid in range(num_batches):
            batch_indices = indices[bid * batch_size : (bid + 1) * batch_size]
            batch = [triples[i] for i in batch_indices]
            X1 = np.zeros((batch_size, 64, 64, 3))
            X2 = np.zeros((batch_size, 64, 64, 3))
            X3 = np.zeros((batch_size, 64, 64, 3))
            for i, (image_filename_l, image_filename_m, image_filename_r) in enumerate(batch):
                if datagens is None or len(datagens) == 0:
                    X1[i] = image_cache[image_filename_l]
                    X2[i] = image_cache[image_filename_m]
                    X3[i] = image_cache[image_filename_r]
                else:
                    X1[i] = datagens[0].random_transform(image_cache[image_filename_l])
                    X2[i] = datagens[1].random_transform(image_cache[image_filename_m])
                    X3[i] = datagens[2].random_transform(image_cache[image_filename_r])
            yield [np.array(X1), np.array(X2), np.array(X3)]
```

Which is used for training my network:

```
base_network = create_base_network(input_shape)
print(base_network.summary())
input_a = Input(shape=input_shape)
input_b = Input(shape=input_shape)
input_c = Input(shape=input_shape)

# because we re-use the same instance `base_network`,
# the weights of the network
# will be shared across the two branches
processed_a = base_network(input_a)
processed_b = base_network(input_b)
processed_c = base_network(input_c)

merged_vector = concatenate([processed_a, processed_b, processed_c], axis=-1, name='merged_layer')

model = Model([input_a, input_b, input_c], merged_vector)
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=BEST_MODEL_FILE, save_best_only=True)
# train

rms = RMSprop()
model.compile(loss=loss_desc_triplet, optimizer=rms, metrics=[accuracy])

history = model.fit_generator(train_pair_gen, 
                             steps_per_epoch=num_train_steps,
                             epochs=epochs,
                             validation_data=val_pair_gen,
                             validation_steps=num_val_steps,
                             callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

However, I get this error message from this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "DeepLearningWithAugmentationWithTriplets.py", line 256, in
>   
>       callbacks=[checkpoint])
>
> File "lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line
>   91, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line
>   1418, in fit_generator
>       initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
>
> File
>   "lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line
>   217, in fit_generator
>       class_weight=class_weight)
>
> File "lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line
>   1211, in train_on_batch
>       class_weight=class_weight)
>
> File "lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line
>   751, in _standardize_user_data
>       exception_prefix='input')
>
> File "lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py",
>   line 102, in standardize_input_data
>       str(len(data)) + ' arrays: ' + str(data)[:200] + '...')
>
> ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays
>   that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected.
>   Expected to see 3 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1
>   arrays: [array([[[[0.36862746, 0.36862746, 0.36862746],
>            [0.36862746, 0.36862746, 0.36862746],
>            [0.36862746, 0.36862746, 0.36862746],
>            ...,
>            [0.41176471, 0.41176471, 0.41176471...

Yet, when I print the next item of the generator it is a list of three arrays:

```
train_pair_gen = triplet_generator(triples_data_train, image_cache, datagens, batch_size)
[X1, X2, X3] = next(train_pair_gen)
print(X1.shape, X2.shape, X3.shape) --> (32, 64, 64, 3) (32, 64, 64, 3) (32, 64, 64, 3)
print("###")
print(len(next(train_pair_gen))) --> 3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Network definition:

> _________________________________________________________________ Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
>   ================================================================= input_131 (InputLayer)       (None, 64, 64, 3)         0
>   _________________________________________________________________ conv2d_100 (Conv2D)          (None, 29, 29, 32)        4736
>   _________________________________________________________________ conv2d_101 (Conv2D)          (None, 8, 8, 64)          73792
>   _________________________________________________________________ conv2d_102 (Conv2D)          (None, 1, 1, 128)         204928
>   _________________________________________________________________ flatten_34 (Flatten)         (None, 128)               0
>   ================================================================= Total params: 283,456 Trainable params: 283,456 Non-trainable params:
>   0
>
> ---